# Could you explain the logic of serial vote reversal?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

[image]

See there are two reversals made on a single day. In the first reversal, it shows `+116/-40`. Is it the same user that made 58 downvotes and 4 upvotes? Could you explain what happens in the background?

Comment: How is 58 downvotes even possible in a day?  (unless it was a multi-attack)

Comment: @SabreTooth As Boltclock explained below, that was not a daily script reversal, but a manual action based on a long-term pattern of serial voting.

Comment: Just click on [time] so the votes are sorted by time instead of [post] and it will make a lot more sense.

Comment: FYI, the "[learn more](http://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)" link highlighted in the screenshot is to http://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed I think. I had a hard time locating it via [help center search](http://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=serial+downvoting) (seventh link down, "serial" doesn't appear in the results).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The one that occurred at 03:00 is part of an automatic routine that occurs once every day at that exact time.

The one that occurred at 16:49 was manually performed by an SE employee to make up for situations that were not caught by the reversal script. Only employees have access to this mechanism; moderators do not.

Any details about who specifically cast these votes are private, but you can pretty much assume, with this many downvotes, that this was the work of at least one user who was targeting you with downvotes, as you had flagged to alert us earlier. It's not clear to me why some upvotes were removed as well — possibly because the employee who removed the votes chose to remove **all** votes the user(s) had ever cast on your posts, up or down, and regardless of when they were cast.

Comment: I'm not sure they have the option to target only upvotes or downvotes. It's pretty rare that a user will have cast votes of the opposite type against a user before serial voting.

Comment: seems like i was largely affected by this user, that he put 58 downvotes on my posts. did you people send a warning message to that user?

Comment: Rest assured we did.

Comment: Seems quite possible that the serial downvoter just miss-clicked a couple of times in his blind rage. And the whole rampage was reverted.

Comment: Looking at that profile now, we're going to need a new tag :-)

Comment: I don't know i just wanted revenge for a downvote.

Comment: @vjdhama: Yeah, uh... don't do that.